# Selecting image and store this selecting info for next page (Tarot card)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making a website that displays multiple tarot cards. And when the user selects the cards that they want, I want to display that selected card on the next page. So I did some code for selecting the cards, but I am not sure about the next part.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scriptstyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test_checkbox() {
                var flag=false;
                var values=document.getElementsByName("lang")
                for(var i=0; i<values.length;i++) {
                    if(values[i].checked) {
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="lang" value="1" />
              <label for="cb1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/100" /></label>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="lang" value="2" />
              <label for="cb2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/100" /></label>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="lang" value="3" />
              <label for="cb3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/100" /></label>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="lang" value="4" />
              <label for="cb4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/4/100" /></label>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  label {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  label::before {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  label img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  
  :checked+label {
    border-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  :checked+label::before {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: rgb(41, 148, 255);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  :checked+label img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

I think I should add some storing information part after

```
if(values[i]).checked) {
~~~}
```

but I am not sure about this part :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need more than CSS and HTML to display anything "on the next page."

My suggestions would be to use PHP GET or POST requests, or use cookies or localstorage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).